# on click event on a single image when all images are displayed using v-for

Tags: html, css, vuejs3

trying to make a min project using vue as i am learning it and ran into an issue dont know why the on click event isnt working to make whatever image i click increase in size

[image: the html and css]

[image: the java script]]

tried moving the on click event from the div to the img and still didnt make  a difference pls any help is helpful

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [why it's not a good idea to post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326).  Following this advice will help improve your question and better your odds of receiving a helpful answer.

Comment: Also, `this.effect === !this.effect` will **never** be true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out, it just looks like you're applying a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Property/JavaScript) and not a [class (CSS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors):

```js
effectsControl() {
    let name = 'effect',
        classes = this.classList;

    if(classes.contains(name))
        classes.remove(name);
    else
        classes.add(name);
}
```